# Increasing bounty points

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I was wondering if there was a method, or if its even feasible, to allow the original poster to increase a bounty?

In essence this equates to a larger enticement to get qualified answers. If the bounty is not enough to involve the experts capable of providing a high quality answer what would be?

Getting high quality answers, one would think, are more important than high quality questions, which in all honesty, most often lack depth and understanding (as a generalization) otherwise they most likely would not be posted.

I think we all hope that the concept of forum/community support sites has not run its course through our social landscape, but to continue the development of future contributors, greater involvement of the higher skilled should be a focus.

A status/points system such as SO, has been working, and hopefully will continue to do so. I can't even speak to the benefits I have reaped, which is why I ask the question. What more can entice high quality answers if the OP can not increase bounty awards?

**UPDATE**: This question in general has the same premise as the referenced duplicate, but the position as explained here in, is targeted at both improving answer quality and involving more highly skilled professionals. As such, this question expands the scope to the suggestion for the betterment of the issues mentioned.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You mean increase it while the bounty is active, e.g. you start bounty of 50 rep, then after three days while it's still active, raise it to 100? Or do you mean increase the limit to be more than 500 for a single bounty?

Comment: I mean, increase while still active. I thought it might add incentive for someone that might have the skills but not the motivation (perhaps). Just thinking of ideas to increase responses. I am aware of the comments that "Good questions get Good Answers" Just looking for other options.

Comment: Ok so yes, I posted in meta.serverfault.com which I mixed up with just Meta, which I thought was the correct site. I searched there and did not find any questions. so it is a dup over here. And further, although a dup on Meta, this was actually submitted as a Feature Request, the supposed Dup has zero answers, and no feedback about adding a feature.

Comment: And by the way, why the down votes with no comments. I thought this was already being addressed? I don't understand the down vote on a feature request without some dialog.

Comment: Downvotes here only mean people don't want to see this feature added to Stack Exchange, that's all. Nothing personal and it is not about the question quality.

Comment: Regarding the update: still doesn't justify whole new feature request  in my opinion, better be posted as answer on the original request. (i.e. explaining why this would be a good idea.)

Comment: I disagree that this is a "whole new feature request" its more of an extension of the bounty function. nothing more, with the added expectation of increasing involvement.

Comment: So you only support my claim that it should stay closed. If it *was* whole new feature request,  it would fit as new feature request, i.e. not closed. Extensions of existing feature requests should come as part of the requests, in my opinion.

Comment: Arguing semantics is counter productive to processing a suggestion for improving the site. Put your wisdom to better use and look to advance the development of the Stack!! Stagnation is death, especially in tech.